# Understanding the meaning of $ \Phi(u,v)=0 $ as a Solution in Lagrange's Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am currently studying [Lagrange's equation](https://soulofmathematics.com/index.php/lagranges-equation/), which is quasi-linear partial differential equation defined by
$ Pp + Qq = R $,
where $ P $, $ Q $, and $ R $ are functions of $ x $, $ y $, and $ z $, where $z$ is a function of $ x $ and $ y $.

To find solution of this type of PDEs a theorem is used which state that the general solution to Lagrange's equation can be represented as $ \Phi(u,v) = 0 $, where $ \Phi $ is an arbitrary function, and $ u(x, y, z) = c_1 $ and $ v(x, y, z) = c_2 $ are two independent solutions of
$ \frac{{dx}}{{P}} = \frac{{dy}}{{Q}} = \frac{{dz}}{{R}} $.

I am struggling to comprehend how an equation, $ \Phi(u,v) = 0 $, can be considered a solution to the original equation. It makes no sense to say that an equation is a solution to another equation. Should not the solution be given in this form $z = f(x, y)?$  Could someone kindly explain the meaning of $ \Phi(u,v) = 0 $ as a solution to Lagrange's equation? Furthermore, I would greatly appreciate clarification on the term "arbitrary function" and its relationship with $ \Phi $.

Thank you.